# Getting "real time" occurence count of values in attribute table for displaying purposes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, count

I'm working with ArcMap 10.2 on a layer of points that I have to move. I'm using the editor to move them. What I also need is to display these points based on how many are sharing the same coordinates X and Y, because that's how I find those I need to move ( I give priority to those points which share coordinates with many other points, for reasons you don't need to be bothered with). Getting a Summary Table from the concatenated X & Y and joining the count back to my points layer is the "standard" way to go, but I need to get a "real time" count of occurence of each value and I cannot extract each time the Summary Table and make the join. I searched for and tried with some python coding in the field calculator but didn't find anything working. Ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this sort of real time analysis except maybe with ArcObjects.

Answer (score 2):

Label your layer using this Python expression:

```
def FindLabel ([FID]):
  f=int([FID])
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  dFids={}
  lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"POINTS")[0]
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,["FID","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
       FD,shp=row
       XY='%s %s' %(round(shp.firstPoint.X,2),round( shp.firstPoint.Y,2))
       if f == FD: aKey=XY
       try: dFids[XY]+=[FD]
       except: dFids[XY]=[FD]
  Fids=dFids[aKey]
  if f == Fids[0] and len(Fids)>1:
    return '<CLR red = "255">%i</CLR>'%len(Fids)
  return ""
```

**It is intended for work with shapefiles, and you have to name your layer "POINTS".**

Move point, click away,F5. Spatial duplicates will be labelled by count of overlaps:

[image]

UPDATED EXPRESSION:

```
dFids={}
def FindLabel ([FID]):
  global dFids
  f=int([FID])
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"POINTS")[0]
  if len(dFids)==0:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,["FID","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        FD,shp=row
        XY='%s %s' %(round(shp.firstPoint.X,2),round( shp.firstPoint.Y,2))
        if f == FD:aKey=XY
        try: dFids[XY]+=[FD]
        except: dFids[XY]=[FD]
  else:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,["FID","SHAPE@"],r'"FID"='+str(f)) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        FD,shp=row
        aKey='%s %s' %(round(shp.firstPoint.X,2),round( shp.firstPoint.Y,2))
  Fids=dFids[aKey]; n=len(Fids)
  if f!=Fids[0] or n==1:return None
  if n==2:return '<CLR green = "255">%i</CLR>'%n
  if n<=4:return '<CLR blue = "255">%i</CLR>'%n
  return '<CLR red = "255">%i</CLR>'%n
```

[image]

It works much faster, because it builds dictionary just once.
With very little effort it can be modified to update symbology field, but it will make it slow again

Comment: Note it is very slow, update tomorrow

Comment: Update tomorrow? What do you mean?
Anyway thanks for the answer. I don't think this would solve my specific problem since I need speed and also need to label the layer with other information. I need it to be coloured or simbolyzed based on the number of points sharing same XY so that I can quickly spot the "most dense" XY among hundreds or thousands of points at a small scale. I wanted to try your solution nonetheless, but got this error: "Carriage returns are not allowed in simple expressions".

Comment: Check "Advanced" box and try again with updated script