# Calculate elevation change in point feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a point feature class with 130 rows that represent the vertices of a trail I generated. I calculated the z height for each verticy/row. Now what I want to do is calculate the elevation change from one row to the next.

[image]

so I want to add a new field called, Z change with the number being how many feet from the below row to the above one.

Comment: Do you have a column that contains sequence order?

Comment: yes if the ObjectID be used as that

Comment: Multipoint features have multiple vertices using a single objectid. You would need to reference the part number as a sequence, or convert the multipoint into a number of point features.

Comment: i used the tool feature vertices to points so there is a unique object ID for each row

Comment: Then you no longer have a multipoint feature class, so your first sentence is misleading.

Comment: true your right il change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked a few days ago [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187509/referencing-other-pointsrows-in-field-calculator/187518#187518).  You would reference the objectID in this case by the sounds of it.

code sample from link:

```
prev=None
def diff(curr): 
  global prev
  if prev is None:
    prev = curr
  res = curr - prev
  prev = curr
  return res
```

Comment: so the curr would be my object iD?

Comment: @ziggy take a look at the linked question, it provides more detail on how to use it

Comment: And this one is missing the expression which is needed for this to work